# pointer comparision with int type in c++

Tags: c++, argv

I executed the below program as: `./aout w`.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argv[1] == "w")
    {
        cout << "this was worked";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "this did not worked";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: `this did not worked`.
I tried executing: `if(&argv[1] == "w")`
`if(argv[1]=='w')`

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer. `"w"` is an array which decays to a pointer. Neither pointer will be equal, ever. For C-style null-terminated string you need to use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). Or convert one of the string to a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Use `strncmp` for `char[]`, `char*` comparison.

Comment: I usually convert the arguments (omitting the first one, since it isn't really an argument) into a vector of string objects as the first thing in main.  `auto args = vector<string>(argv+1, argv+argc);`  Much easier to work with `args` in C++.

Comment: Why do you think you're comparing a pointer with an int? Which expression do you believe to be an int type?

Comment: @Eljay I recommend a span of string views to skip unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Useless I assume the `if(argv[1]=='w')` attempt would give such a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
if (argv[1] == "w")
```

is equivalent to

```
char const* p1 = argv[1];
char const* p2 = "w";
if ( p1 == p2 )
```

i.e. you are comparing two pointers, not the strings that the pointers point to.

You can use `std::strcmp`. However, since you are using C++, you might as well use `std::string`.

```
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "w")
```

If you are able to use C++17, you may use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) too.

```
if (std::string_view(argv[1]) == "w")
```

Comment: strcmp doesnot worksit works same as argv[1]=="w"

Comment: Thanks` if (std::string(argv[1]) == "w")` was effective does std::string() function changes char** to char*

Comment: `if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "w") == 0)` should work.

Comment: `std::string(argv[1])` constructs a `std::string` object. It does not change `char**` to `char*`. This question makes me think that you should spend some time learning the basics of the language and the standard library from a [good textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3):

If you compare arrays and pointers using the equality operator, then you are comparing whether they are the same array or point to the same object. You aren't comparing the content of the arrays or pointed elements. Since `argv[1]` points to a different array than the string literal, they compare unequal regardless of their content.

> tried executing: `if(&argv[1] == "w")`

Now, you're comparing `char**` to a `const char*` (after array decay). Comparing pointers of unrelated types doesn't make much sense.

> `if(argv[1]=='w')`.

Now, you're comparing `char*` to `char`. Comparing a pointer to a char doesn't make much sense.

---

To compare the content of two strings, A good solution is to use a string view as either or both of the operands. It's a small change:

```
 using namespace std::literals;
 if (argv[1] == "w"sv)
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need the include for string_view and the `using namespace std::literals` for this one to work

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Hmm, the `using namespace std;` from the example was sufficient when I tested. Strange; ADL shouldn't apply here either.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed `usign namespace std;` from OP's code. My apologies

Comment: When I do`cout<<argv[1]<<endl; `gives me the w

Comment: @Chintusharma That is to be expected.